# Difference between /path/to/env/bin/python setup.py and python setup.py in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

This is a silly question but here it goes.

Usually, when I need to install a package in a virtual environment that for some reason is not playing nice with PIP , I activate such environment and then run `/path/to/env/bin/python setup.py`. This works fine but I have seen that some people just run `python setup.py`. Is it an omission of the full path? Or maybe, provided the virtual environment is activated, `python setup.py` installs the package in a virtual environment automatically. I don't know which one is correct.

Note: I don't want to mess up my clean Linux installation testing the hard way, so I thought it would be better to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have activated the virtualenv in your shell, there is no difference. The obvious difference is that using the explicit path means you'll definitely get the version you expect.

Comment: You mean in case I forget to activate the environment and then use python setup.py? Then activating the environment AND using the full path is redundant?